# Where to put error/break statement?

Tags: debugging, error-handling

This isn't related to a specific language, although I am writing in Java, but I was wondering how an if/else statement that was designed to catch a bad input should be structured, i.e. whether I should put the break statement first or the code first, or if it is largely semantics and doesn't matter. Here is an example:

Should it be:

```
if (faultyInput):
    return Null;
else:
    doActions();
```

or

```
if (!faultyInput):
    doActions();
else:
    return Null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must write:

```
if(faultyInput)  retun null;  
doActions();
```

No need to include the else statement, because there is already the return keyword.
It will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there is no single correct way to write the code. Both situations will give you exact same result. You should just do whichever you feel is what you want and will help you understand your code better.